# Tmux not working in Xterm on Debian Stable

Tags: debian, terminal, xorg, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux on my computer and it runs perfectly as root, but I'd rather run it under my own account. When I run it with my account, I get a variety of error messages that include "Cannot establish any listening sockets" and another message that "Server is already active for display 0". I try to follow the instructions inside the error messages but it just brings me in circles. Let me know what I should try or what other information I should post. I'm a first timer here, so I might make mistakes with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, you've tried to set up your `~/.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) to automatically start Xorg on login. The problem is, each tmux window runs the `.profile` scripts *again*, and tries to start Xorg inside Xorg. So if that's the case, you need to add additional checks.

For example, if you have the `startx` command in ~/.profile, replace it with:

```
if [ "$(tty)" = /dev/tty1 ]; then
    startx
fi
```

This will run startx only when logging in to the 1st text console (tty1). It doesn't just fix tmux, but also fixes SSH and "display managers" like GDM & LightDM, as well as avoiding duplicate Xorgs in general.

Comment: @t0ofpaste, if that's the case, consider rather using [`nodm`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nodm) instead of starting X by hand or auto-starting it from a console login session.

Comment: Good guess, indeed!

Comment: You are magical... Wow. Yea, I actually added an "exec xinit" inside my .profile and after changing my code to yours, it started working. Thanks a ton man. This problem has been terrorizing me for days! :P